# Sharepoint - Regional settings

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have the regional settings set to UK in Sharepoint.
The Regional settings are also set to UK.
I have a date picker in the a custom web part.
This is sometimes showing in English US and sometimes English UK. 
I have load balanced environment so perhaps it could be that one server is set correctly and one is not.

Is there any where else where I need to check for regional settings. I have checked the server settings from control panel, and the settings in the site collection?
Could there me any other reason why the date picker is acting this way please?

Thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `Sharepoint:DateTimeControl` tag use `LocaleID="2057"` to show the date in UK format.
I think it will solve your problem.
Thanks,

Aniket Banerjee,
Senior Software Developer,
Mindfire Solutions